# Remove access for facebook app based on client_id

Tags: facebook

How do you remove access to a Facebook app based on the client_id it used?

E.g. assuming someone clicks on a link that looks like this:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=client_id_string&redirect_uri=
https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html&scope=basic_info,email,public_profile,
user_about_me,user_activities,user_birthday,user_education_history,user_friends,
user_interests,user_likes,user_location,user_photos,user_relationship_details&
response_type=token
```

and all they have is the client_id_string how do they then revoke access via Facebook?

Answer (score 1):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/permissions

See "Revoking Permissions" in the docs. You can´t remove the App itself, but you can remove permissions.

> You can revoke a specific permission by making a call to a Graph API
>   endpoint:
>
> DELETE /{user-id}/permissions/{permission-name}
>
> This request must be made with a user access token or an app access
>   token for the current app. If the request is successful, you will
>   receive a response of true.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: i´ve included the relevant part.